# Can't get range correct in SQL

Tags: python, windows, macos, range

I am struggling with a part of my course I am doing and I would like your help please.

My instructor is typing in his Mac command console

> python generate_actions.py 1000000 big_actions.csv

However, I am using Windows with cmd, and I am typing in the same code, however it is coming up with

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "generate_actions.py", line 33, in < module>
>
> generate(int(sys.argv[1]), sys.argv[2])
>
> File "generate_actions.py", line 26, in generate
>
> for j in xrange(a):
>
> NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined

Can someone help me by telling me what am I doing wrong, and how can I get the range to work please? We are using Python 3, so my instructor said to change it from xrange to range, but I do not know what to do.

Thank you.

Comment: you're asking us to debug code that you haven't posted....

Comment: You have to open generate_actions.py in a text editor (e.g. Notepad or Wordpad) and change that line, then save it and run that command again.

Comment: Please post the content in `generate_actions.py` which is giving you this error.

Comment: `xrange` was deprecated in python 3.x. Replace `xrange` with `range` in your code.